# Split contents of an Access field into separate variables in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access, variables, datatable

I have an Access table containing a field with multiple dates (ex: 11/22/2022, 11/23/2022, 11/24/2022) that needs to be split into usable variables. The field could contain 1 to 40 dates, it's unknown at any given time.

I have been unable to find any examples of this being done, any links or ideas anyone might know of?

Comment: Any time you think "variable variables" or like "Variable number of variables" think instead "Array" or, often times even better "Dictionary". As this data exists in a table, though, I would question if you even need an array to hold this. Querying the table and having the data available in a DAO recordset would suffice, no?

Comment: @JNevill It does, however, I need to use the information contained in the recordset to query another table to get a reason. So the field could have an infinite number of dates (in reality more like 7 max) all with different reasons that will need to be separated for detailing out. So 11/22/2022 has a reason of Thanksgiving week and 12/23/2022 has a reason of Christmas Week.

Comment: Look at the `Split` function to get the data into an array, which you can then loop (`LBound` and `UBound` will give the limits of the array).

Comment: Got it. I missed that you have more than one value stored in a single entry. That's some ugly stuff. Splitting the string to an array is definitely the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your form, create a *combo- or listbox*. Name it, say, EventDate.

Set its *RowSourceType* property to *ValueList*.

Insert code like this in the *OnCurrent* event of the form:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Me!EventDate.RowSource = Nz(Me!YourMultiDateField.Value)

End Sub
```

This will list the dates with the option to select one.